# Error installing an assembly into COM+

Tags: .net, com, com+, dllregistration

I am using Managed C++ i.e accessing the .Net Framework capabilities from my C++ code.
The problematic code in question is being invoked from a custom action dll and  is part of one of our .msp packages.

Scenario:
We are making use of  [`RegistrationHelper::InstallAssembly Method (String, String%, String%, InstallationFlags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxt2z474.aspx) from the `System.EnterpriseServices` namespace to install an assembly into COM+.
The above piece of code installs an assembly into COM+ by making use of a type library file on the disk.

This piece of code is run from the system context.
We are experiencing failures with the above method on 20% of the servers. 
The code fails with the following exception:

> *System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException: Could not install type library '[path to .tlb file]' into application '[name of the application]'.
>      at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationDriver.InstallAssembly(RegistrationConfig regConfig, Object obSync)
>      at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.InstallAssemblyFromConfig(RegistrationConfig& regConfig)
>      at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.InstallAssembly(String assembly, String& application, String partition, String& tlb, InstallationFlags installFlags)
>      at System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationHelper.InstallAssembly(String assembly, String& application, String& tlb, InstallationFlags installFlags)
>      at ComPlusRegistrationWrapper.CtxRegsvcs.RegisterComPlus(String Assembly, String ApplicationName, String TLB)*

The above exception has been captured by making use of `ToString()` method of the System.Exception class.

Please note that in the above exception:
[path to .tlb file] - path to the type library file on the disk
[name of the application] - name of the COM+ application.

The code is being executed on  Windows 2008 R2.
Reflector confirms that the assembly in question is compiled against .Net FW 2.0

I am at loss to understand as to why this is occurring only on a subset of servers.

To gather more data, this is what i have thought of:

-Asking the customer to run ctxregsvcs.exe to install the assembly manually into COM+ and see if that succeeds.

Does anyone have any pointers as to how this could be debugged further?